# Flask testing keeps failing

Tags: python, flask, flask-testing

So I have web app where if the user is logged in, he cannot sign up. Instead he is redirected and a message saying he cannot sign up is flashed.

The problem is I can't test it for some reason.

Here is the view

```
@users_template.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = RegisterationForm()
    if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.is_active:  # prevent the user from seeing the register page if he's already logged in
        flash('You cannot sign up while you\'re logged in')
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        username = form.username.data
        password = form.password.data
        user = User(username=username, password=password)
        if db.session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first() is None:
            current_app.logger.info('<{}> did not register before. Registering him/her now'.format(username))
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Thank you for registering. Please login now')
            return redirect(url_for('users.login'))
        else:  # the user name has been registered before
            flash('You already registered')
    return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
```

Now in my test module I have this method

```
def test_signup_page_requires_logout(self):
    data_to_signup = {'username': 'mustafa1', 'password': 'mustafa1',
            'confirm_password': 'mustafa1'}
    data_to_login = {'username': 'mustafa1', 'password': 'mustafa1'}
    # with statement preserves the request context for the current_user
    with self.client:
        self.client.post('/signup', data=data_to_signup)
        self.client.post('/login', data=data_to_login)
        response = self.client.get('/signup', follow_redirects=True)
        assert b'You cannot sign up while you\'re logged in' in response.data
```

What's even more confusing is that this structure works for other methods

```
def test_headquarter_after_login(self):
    data_to_signup = {'username': 'mustafa1', 'password': 'mustafa1',
            'confirm_password': 'mustafa1'}
    data_to_login = {'username': 'mustafa1', 'password': 'mustafa1'}
    with self.client:
        self.client.post('/signup', data=data_to_signup)
        self.client.post('/login', data=data_to_login)
        response = self.client.get('/headquarter')
        assert b'Headquarter page' in response.data
```

EDIT: here is the login view

```
from .. import bcrypt
@users_template.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit() and request.method == 'POST':
        username = form.username.data
        password = form.password.data

        user = User.query.filter(User.username == username).first()

        if user is not None and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):  # authenticate
            login_user(user)  # then log the user in
            flash('You are logged in')
            return redirect(url_for('main.home'))

        else:
            flash('Incorrect username or password')  # if username is wrong, it will be caught by the error handling above
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)  # for a GET request
```

This is the error (I'm using py.test fyi)

```
            assert current_user.is_active() == True
            assert current_user.is_authenticated() == True
>           assert b'You cannot sign up while you\'re logged in' in response.data
E           AssertionError: assert b"You cannot sign up while you're logged in" in b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" cont...jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>\n    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>\n  </body>\n</html>\n'
E            +  where b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" cont...jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>\n    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>\n  </body>\n</html>\n' = <TestResponse 3874 bytes [200 OK]>.
```

This is to display the flashed messages in all my templates(It's in my "base.html" which I inherit from)

```
    {% if get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
            <div class='container'>
                    <span class='alert alert-info'>
                        <small>{{ message }}</small>
                    </span>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

I've made more tests using the flashed messages and it worked fine.
Like this one for testing the user signup

```
assert b'Thank you for registering. Please login now' in response.data
```

Comment: Please paste here also login view.

Comment: @turkus It's done

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion no:

1. Because of this line:

   ```
   if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.is_active:
   ```

   current_user has his `is_active` flag set as `False`. If I'm not right, then please paste test error.
2. Another clue could be lack of flash messages in home template. Put this code below in for example `flashMessages.html`:

   ```
   {% macro render_flashMessages() %}
       {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
           {% if messages %}
           <ul class="list-unstyled">
               {% for message in messages %}
               <li><div class="alert alert-info">{{ message|safe }}</div></li>
               {% endfor %}
           </ul>
           {% endif %}
       {% endwith %}
   {% endmacro %}
   ```

   then you can use it in this way in `home.html`:

   ```
   {% from "flashMessages.html" import render_flashMessages %}

   {{ render_flashMessages() }}
   ```
3. Next thing to check is to use assert with something else than response.data, if you're using [Flask-WebTest](https://flask-webtest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can try:

   ```
   assert b'You cannot sign up while you\'re logged in' in response.flashes[0][1]
   ```

   Where `flashes` is:

   > List of tuples (category, message) containing messages that were flashed during request.
4. But if you're not using FlaskWebTest, you can check session:

   ```
   from flask import session

   session['_flashes'][0][1]
   ```

Comment: I've included the error. Both the is_active and is_authenticated are in fact True

Comment: @MAA does it work or still nothing, because I have something more in my mind.

Comment: First thank you for following up with me. Yeah I have in my "base.html" (which I subclass in all my jinja2 templates) {% block content %}. Then after it I have the part where I include the flashed message in all the templates. Check the original post

Comment: @MAA That's why we are here :) Updated.